# Generic Wildcards with Map

Tags: java, generics

```
class SuperCl  {}
class A extends SuperCl {}
class B extends SuperCl {}

static void method(Map<Integer, List<? extends SuperCl>> map) {}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    method(new HashMap<Integer, List<A>>()); //ERROR
}
```

The compile time error is that the types are incompatible:
`Map<Integer, List<A>>` cannot be converted to `Map<Integer, List<? extends SuperCl>>`

How can I fix it and where does the error come from?
I assume it comes from the "method" being static.

EDIT: I changed the map implementation to HashMap (copy error) - this should not change anything

Comment: My bad @Maarten-reinstateMonica, you are correct

Comment: You were missing a final `>` on the generic type parameters of the method. Fixed it for you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your method to

```
static <T extends SuperCl> void method(Map<Integer, List<T>> map) {
}
```

Edit: The error mainly comes from the use of a nested generic. If you would have something like

```
static void method (List<? extends SuperC1> list) {

}

public static void main (String[] args) {
  List<A> list = new ArrayList<>();

  method(list);
}
```

you would not get a compile time error because `A` satisfies `? extends SuperCl`.

Comment: Yes makes sense and works as expected. I have never seen the generic in front of a method.

Answer (score 3):

A `HashMap<Integer, List<A>>` isn't a `Map<Integer, List<? extends SuperCl>>`, because you can add any type of `List<? extends SuperCl>` to the latter.

For example:

```
Map<Integer, List<A>> original = new HashMap<Integer, List<A>>();
// Raw types to intentionally break the type system.
Map<Integer, List<? extends SuperCl>> map = (Map) original;

List<B> listOfB = new ArrayList<>();
listOfB.add(new B());
map.put(0, listOfB);

List<A> listOfA = original.values().iterator().next();
A item = listOfA.get(0);  // ClassCastException.
```

If you could do that, you'd have been able to add a value that's not a `List<A>` to it. Hence it's not allowed.

---

You could change the type in the method signature to this, for example:

```
Map<Integer, ? extends List<? extends SuperCl>>
```

and that would be fine, because you can't put any value into that (other than literal `null`).

Comment: Really nice example

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
    class SuperCl  {}
    class A extends SuperCl {}
    class B extends SuperCl {}

    static <T extends SuperCl> void method(Map<Integer, List<T>> map) {}

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        method(new HashMap<Integer, List<A>>()); //NO MORE ERROR
    }
```

I simply moved the generics:

```
<T extends SuperCl>
```

to the static method declaration. This makes it verifiable at compile time. On the other hand, having that generic at the method argument is not compile time verifiable.

Answer (score 0):

Generics are invariant. For parameterized types to be compatible, their type arguments must match *exactly*, unless one of them is a wildcard at the top level. `Map<Integer, List<A>>` is not a subtype of `Map<Integer, List<? extends SuperCl>>` because `List<A>` is not identical to `List<? extends SuperCl>`. Yes, `List<A>` is a *subtype* of `List<? extends SuperCl>`, but they are not identical, which is what is needed.

As you may know, `List<Dog>` is not a subtype of `List<Animal>`, even though `Dog` is a subtype of `Animal`. It's the same situation here. A subtype relationship of the type arguments does not lead to a subtype relationship of the parameterized types (that would be called "covariant"; Java array types are covariant, but generics are not).

One solution to this is to use a wildcard at the top level. For example, `List<Dog>` *is* a subtype of `List<? extends Animal>`. Similarly in your case, `Map<Integer, List<A>>` *is* a subtype of `Map<Integer, ? extends List<? extends SuperCl>>`. So you can declare your method as:

```
static void method(Map<Integer, ? extends List<? extends SuperCl>> map) {}
```